# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError (bad decrypt) for SymmetricEncryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, openssl

I am using the symmetric-encryption ruby gem for encrypting/decrypting email addresses in a Rails app. The encryption/decryption is working fine in the development environment, however, on Heroku I am receiving a bad decrypt error. I am unsure of the issue, both keys have been configured on Heroku. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you include more details in your question? Examples of the errors you are seeing and the kind of input you're trying to pass to that gem would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I figured out the issue, I was testing development encryptions against production decryptions.